# pg_basebackup on Google Cloud SQL database

Tags: database, postgresql, google-cloud-sql, postgresql-9.6, cloud-sql-proxy

I'm currently experimenting with Googles Cloud SQL and I'm facing the following problem:

**Goal**

I want to download a base-backup and after that the upcoming WAL-files to implement on-prem failover strategies for my Cloud-SQL hosted PostgreSQL database.

**What I've tried & what went wrong**

The commands `pg_dump` and `pg_dumpall` worked fine after some edits, but I can't get the `pg_basebackup` command to deliver files.

I'm receiving the following error:

```sh
pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "[local]", user "postgres", SSL off
```

**Thoughts**

It seems to me that Google doesn't allow doing "Continous Archiving" on my own, which would be fatal for on-prem failover strategies and would explicitly *force* me to use Google Cloud SQL's archiving methods.

**Question**

Does anyone use PITR techniques on their Cloud SQL Postgres instances and has a workaround for this?

Comment: You replication protocol outside Googles Cloud SQL is forbidden by google. You basically cannot use `pg_basebackup`.

Comment: @SahapAsci So the only way for on-prem backups from Cloud SQL hosted postgres databases is with `pg_dump` and `pg_dumpall`?

Comment: AFAIK there is no PITR feature implemented yet. Check [Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL features](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/features) and [Overview of backups](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/backup-recovery/backups)

Comment: I afraid  @SahapAsci might be right, although I wasn't able to find any doc about it... BTW Can I ask how do connect to postgre on cloud SQL?

Comment: @vitooh There are different options connecting to your Cloud SQL postgres, consider reading the official Documentation [of Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/how-to#connecting-to-instances).

Comment: On Google docs https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/features#features_not_yet_available there is information that PITR is "not yet" available. There is no information about exact timing, but anyway it should be available soon